# Working with Highchart Treemaps (drilldown)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, highcharts

I have a problem with HighChart Treemaps. Ive been working on a custom algorithm with equal tiles. Though i got my custom algorithm to work (Thanks to other SO questions) , I'm not able to achieve drilldown. The custom algorithm works perfectly for the parent nodes. When I click on a parent, Only the latest child covers the entire map. I tried customizing the algo, but it went nowhere.

Any help is highly appreciated. Code posted on JSfiddle. And the green tile has children. Purple parent doesn't have one.

```
function myFunction(parent, children) {
var x = parent.x,
        y = parent.y,
    w=20,
    h=20,i,j,
        childrenAreas = [];
        console.log(parent);
        console.log(children);
Highcharts.each(children, function(child) {   


    if(child.level == 1)
    {
    //console.log("if part"+child.i+" "+x+ " "+y);
    if(x>=parent.width)
       {
       x=parent.x;
       y+=h;

       }
       else
       {
     x+=w;
   }

    }
    else
    {
         //console.log(child);


    } 
childrenAreas.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: w,
        height: h
    });
 //console.log(parent.x+w);



});
//console.log(childrenAreas);
return childrenAreas;
```

};

[Complete code on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99rbh2qj/1/)

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you problem is connected with how drilldown works in treemap. Your layout algorithm worked well, but when you are clicking on your point, the chart is rescalling (functionality similar to zooming into your point) and that is the reason why you have different size of your points.

You can make some calculations that will change your second level points width, so after rescalling they will have the same width as your previous level.

```
    Highcharts.each(children, function(child, i) {
  if (child.level === 1) {
    width = parent.width;
    height = parent.height;
    x = parent.x + i * w;
    childrenAreas.push({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: w,
      height: h
    });
  } else {
    pointW = w * w / width;
    pointH = h * h / height;
    x = parent.x + i * pointW;
    childrenAreas.push({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: pointW,
      height: pointH
    });
  }
});
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/99rbh2qj/8/

You can also use standard Highcharts drilldown module in your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/99rbh2qj/5/

Best regards.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot! +1 for the explanation! :)

Comment: Hey @Grzegorz , I have a problem. If i start adding more elements to the data array, it doesn't get displayed nor it the tiles get displayed in the next line. How do i display the tiles after the canvas's width gets exhausted? Now, the max no of elements that gets displayed is 11. After 11, any number of elements i push to the array will not get displayed. Please help.

Comment: You can see this example with standard Highcharts drilldown: http://jsfiddle.net/99rbh2qj/9/ I have changed custom function a little bit

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz .cant something be done for the existing algorithm? without using the drilldown.js. Now if i set allowDrilldown = true, only one child appears occupying the entire screen. basically, same prob as earlier (re scaling issue)

Comment: Hi, This is possible (with similar algorithm) but this is much more complicated. Here you can find an example how your function may work: http://jsfiddle.net/99rbh2qj/11/

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz . Will try this out :) Appreciate your help.